# Magento 1.6 Forgotten Password Returning New Password as Blank

Tags: templates, magento

I have been having this problem since i upgraded my sites from Magento 1.3 - Magento 1.6 .

When a customer requests a new password using the Forgotten Password field they recieve an email however the new password comes through as blank.

Dear, **********,

Your new password is:

You can change your password at any time by logging into your account.

Thank you again.

I have read alot of different fixes all similaring the fact that the customer.xml may be out of date, I have tryed alot of fixes and none seem to work. Any help on the topic would be much appreciated.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen before. In my case it was because a customised template had been created, and in the newer version of Magento it changes how this process works slightly. Previously a new password was generated and sent plain text. In newer version it simply sends a link which you can follow to manually specify your new password (which in my opinion is much better functionality). Check which template it used here...

```
System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Password Options > Forgot Email Template
```

If it is not the default template then go to `System > Transactional Emails` and generate a new forgot password e-mail and either modify as needed then change this to be the used e-mail (via the configuration mentioned previously). Or perhaps easier, copy the main content (echo'ing of the link) into your current template.

Comment: Hi Cags, Thanks for the reply, I tryed the above and when i click on the link in the email I get the following error:                                                                               
Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerId() on a non-object in /home/basketsg/public_html/magentouk/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 587                                                                                                                                     Do you have any ideas as to why this is? Thanks